# Threshold of connectivity in a random graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, asymptotics, random-graphs

I am trying to understand the proof to a random graph problem (the threshold for connectivity of $G \sim G(n,p)$ being $\frac{logn}{n}$). I am struggling to see exactly why the following holds:

$\text{When } p^{*} \ll p,\\
n(1-p) ^{n-1} \leq ne^{-p(n-1)} = o(ne^{-\log n}) = o(1).\\$

I am aware that the following inequalities may be used in the derivation but my further deductions (after the $\implies$ symbol) show that the LHS of ($\text{*}$) and RHS of ($\text{**}$) are both greater or equal to the same quantity. However, the line of the proof provided above states something different, to which I am unable to arrive.

$\text{(*) }(1-p)^{n-1} \geq 1 - (n - 1)p, \forall 0 \leq p \leq 1, \text{and}\\
\text{(**) }e^{p} \geq p + 1, \forall p \implies e^{-p(n-1)} \geq 1-(n-1)p.$

Another amateurish question follows here - is the following the case in the last part of the aforementioned line from the proof:
$ne^{-\log n} = nn^{-1} \text{?}$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, as I stated in the post, I cannot arrive at the last line of the proof. I've reported my derivations which lead me nowhere w.r.t. the proof, so the question is basically, how given the two inequalities (before my own intervention after the $\therefore$ symbol) the line of the proof can be obtained?

Comment: Something like the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

$$1-p\leqslant\mathrm e^{-p}\implies(1-p)^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{-np}\implies n(1-p)^n\leqslant n\mathrm e^{-np}\quad\&\qquad\mathrm e^{-c\log x}=x^{-c}$$
**Edit:** The starting point $1-p\leqslant\mathrm e^{-p}$ (worth remembering in other contexts as well) can be proven in a wealth of different ways. For example, it follows from the fact that $\mathrm e^{-x}\leqslant1$ for every $x\geqslant0$ hence, for every $p\geqslant0$,
$$
p=\int_0^p\mathrm dx\geqslant\int_0^p\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx=1-\mathrm e^{-p}.
$$

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply once again! For the second equation I understand how it works (which confirmed my understanding) but still I do not see the connection between the first one, the line that concludes the formal proof, and the inequalities I've provided that should facilitate arriving at the proof. Could you, please, elaborate on it?

Comment: Once again, what is your question is not very clear but if the goal is to prove that $n(1−p)^n⩽ne^{−np}$, well, my answer does that.

Comment: So how do you arrive at $(1-p) \leqslant \mathrm{e}^{-p}$? Or is it another inequality?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: A favorite way to prove $1-p \leq e^{-p}$ of mine is to note that $f(x) = e^{-x}$ is convex; hence the graph of $f(x)$ lies above its tangent line at $x=0$ (i.e. $y=1-x$)